# Finding URL using Unit test case of PHP

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm new to PHP. I've started working on writing unit test case. I'm confused how to get the URL of the page using unit test case. If I run the application, I can get the URL. But, how do I get it using unit test case? I'd like to check in the URL whether I've **admin** keyword in the URL. Can any one suggest me in this scenario? Here is my code.

**sample.php**

```php
function isURL(){
            
    $urlPath=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // Get URL from the browser.
    $adminString = 'admin';
    $Url_chk=strpos($urlPath, $adminString); // Check whether 'admin' keyword is available in URL.
    return $Url_chk;    
}
```

**Test Unit case**

```php
public function testStoreFrontUrl(){    

    $url = isURLStorefront();
    echo "URL::".$url;
    $storeFrontUrl = 'www.google.com';
    $this->assertEquals('www.google.com', $storeFrontUrl);
}
```

I know the above uint `REQUEST_URI`. Please suggest me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing that stops you from assigning the superglobal yourself.

```
public function testStoreFrontValidUrl() {
  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = 'www.foobar.com/admin/';
  $url = isURLStoreFront();
  $this->assertNotEquals($url, -1);
}
```

Also, if you write a method called 'isFoo()', it generally means that the method returns a boolean. It's just good practice to follow naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me check.

Comment: But, whether I give admin or not in the URL, the test is passing? How can I check when the test is failing?